# Binding JBoss to IP Address

Tags: binding, jboss

I am running a JBoss instance on a linux server
I am using the ./run.sh -b

This is not working what could be the reason.

I am unable to share the error message details as of now will post it when I can, till then any alternatives or solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -b [IP-Address|Hostname] option binds services to the given interface, using 0.0.0.0 as IP makes the services available to all interfaces.

It really depends on the error message I suppose you receive a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`  In this case you need to identify to service already bound to this port and disable or reconfigure it. Alternativly you could reconfigure you [jboss](http://community.jboss.org/thread/59995?tstart=0)